# sql Alter table: create a column base on datediff between 2 columns

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I want to creat a computed column based on datediff function between 2 existing columns (date1 and date2). (in days)

date1 and date2 are sql DATE type.

What I tried without sucess :

```
     ALTER TABLE my_table ADD lenght AS datediff('dd', date1, date2)
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GENERATED column is automatically updated when the values it refers to in other columns change. The correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD length INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATEDIFF('day', date1, date2))
```

Comment: Great but not working on HSQLDB Unexpected token ALWAYS, requires BY in statement...

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of HSQLDB. I checked my answer and corrected it as I found out it needed parentheses and it now works fine in HSQLDB versions 2.3x and later.

Comment: Yes, I am using LibreOffice

Comment: You can try the new HSQLDB versions as external database in LibreOffice. See http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=17567

Comment: @fredt How to solve this, if i want datediff between current date and a date column

Comment: @Nobita - it is not allowed because current_date changes all the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD lenght AS int;

UPDATE my_table SET lenght = DateDiff('dd', date1, date2);

-- Don't forget to add a trigger that fires on updated and inserted rows that will keep the value of lenght valid if the date1 or date2 changes
```

Comment: For me: ALTER TABLE my_table ADD lenght  int;